# Active Directory authorization

Tags: iis, web-config, authorization, active-directory-group

I have windows authentication. When a user access the application need to check the username from the windows and compare with the active directory group for the username and if username exists should show the landing page else should redirect to error page through web.config only. 
So can anyone help me with this. and what is impersonate in web.config?

Comment: This should be a routine IIS setting, applicable to the entire (internal) web-site: &nbsp; only members of specified AD groups are allowed to access *any* part of the site. And, therefore, the site itself doesn't have to concern itself with *authentication,* because, "if they're here, they must be who we know they are, and they must be authorized to be here." Furthermore, IIS provides known-good information about the connected user through environment-variables (and other means) if the application wishes to do further *authorization* tests of its own.

Comment: Hi mike, Can you please share the settings

Answer (score 0):

Worked after couple of trails.

To allow the users only under the Active directory groups should be given within the Authorization tag.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
<allow roles="ActiveDirectory1"/>
<allow roles="ActiveDirectory2"/>
<Deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```